# How do you reference Array.prototype.slice.call()?

Tags: javascript, arrays, slice

I am writing a script in which I need to clone arrays in many different places.  For this reason, I would like to do the following to emulate a cloning function:

```
var clone = [].slice.call;
var arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
var arr2 = clone(arr1, 0);
```

Unfortunately, the above code results in:  `TypeError: object is not a function`.  I realize there are many functions out there to do deep cloning and shallow copies but I just want to use the built in method.  Interestingly enough, the following does work:

```
var clone = [].slice;
var arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
var arr2 = clone.call(arr1, 0);
```

Does anyone know why the first block doesn't work while the second does?  Is there any way to reference a functions call and apply functions without throwing errors when calling the referenced function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have to definitely agree with both Felix King and pimvdb.  I think the only drawback to using the Function.protoytpe.bind() function is the fact that this is not a function that is available in all browsers (IE6 for example).  An alternative would be to use a JavaScript library that provides the curry() function.  Another alternative would be to define a function which gives you the ability to retrieve the call function for any other function.  Here is a definition that I [posted on my blog](http://gotochriswest.com/blog/2011/06/29/javascript-function-prototype-getcall/) for such a function which I called getCall():

```
Function.prototype.getCall = function() {
  var realFn = this;
  return function(objThis) {
    return realFn.apply(objThis, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
  };
};
```

Now, with this definition, you could do the following to get a reference to the call function of the slice function:

```
var slice = [].slice.getCall();
```

Comment: Awesome!  This is almost exactly what I was looking for.  I am glad that you pointed out the lack of the bind function in all browsers.  Thank you so much!

Comment: +1 Nice little method. Just for the record, there is a `.bind` replacement: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind. I prefer the `.getCall` solution, though :)

Comment: Remember that the .bind replacement is only a partial solution, as stated by Mozilla.  In fact, that is the main reason why I will not be including that in the next version of jPaq.

Answer (score 3):

You can clone an array by calling `slice` directly:

```
var arr2 = arr1.slice();
```

If you want a `clone` function, you can do:

```
var clone = function(arr) { return arr.slice(); };
```

If you really want to prototype function (which is not necessary as long as the function is not overwritten):

```
var clone = function(arr) { return [].slice.call(arr); };
```

---

**Why can't you reference `call` or `apply` directly?**

It does not work for the same reason assigning a method of an object to a variable does not "work".

If you call `func.call()` then `this` inside `call`  will be a reference to `func`, a function object.

If you assign `call` to a variable then the context is lost. You have a reference to the generic `call` function. Thus you'd have to pass the correct context (the method you want to apply `call` to) as first parameter to `call` again:

```
var clone = [].slice.call;
var arr2 = clone.call([].slice, arr1);
```

This is not really an improvement and quite confusing.

`call` and `apply` are methods that every functions inherits from `Function.prototype`. Functions don't have their own version of them. `[].slice.call === [].splice.call` yields `true`.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but I am not asking for a cloning function so much as I am asking why I can't seem to use a reference to the call function or apply function of another function.

Comment: Excellent test for [].slice.call === [].splice.call.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is the scope of the function, i.e. what "this" is. I'm not sure what the correct technical terms are, but the "this" is not the same when a function is called "stand alone" or as a property of an object.

```
var myObj = {};
myObj.foo = function () {
    console.log(this.bar);
};
myObj.bar = 1234;

var fooRef = myObj.foo;

myObj.foo(); // 1234
fooRef(); // undefined
```

You can however create a function that wraps a call to the function and passes on all the arguments:

```
var fooEncapsulated = function () {
    return myObj.foo.apply(myObj, arguments);
}

fooEncapsulated(); // 1234
```

For the record, the most common way of doing this is:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(myArray, other, arguments, here);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but I really want to know how I can reference the call function of another function.  I already know about the slice function.

Comment: Just updated my answer. To answer your comment specifically, you can't. You need to encapsulate it. This is a feature in JavaScript.

Comment: I think the answer basically comes down to "you can't".  From this answer basically you're saving the function to a variable, but it doesn't save the context in which it would be called.  So I think your best bet is @felix's 3rd answer, wrap it in a function.

Comment: @primvdb: `bind` is not supported in a large array of browsers, and is  technically the same as wrapping it manually anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `whatever_function.call` is equal to `Function.prototype.call`. Thus, you effectively save a reference to `Function.prototype.call` and the information that it is the slice function is lost.

Compare it with a custom function:

```
Function.prototype.custom = function() { console.log(this) };

[].slice.custom(); // logs slice function

var ref = [].slice.custom;
ref(); // logs window object
```

A method of keeping the `this` value from being changed is using `Function.prototype.bind`:

```
var ref = [].slice.call.bind([].slice);
```

Now,

```
ref([1,2,3], 1); // [2, 3]
```

because when calling the `.call` function, the `this` value is bound to the slice function and everything works as expected.

Comment: Shouldn't `Function.prototype.call.bind( Array.prototype.slice )` perform better?

Answer (score 0):

Sweet and simple:

```
slice = Function.prototype.call.bind(Array.prototype.slice);
slice([1,2,3]); // [1,2,3]
slice({length:3,0:1,1:2,2:3}); // [1,2,3]
```