# "object is not a function" when saving function.call to a variable

Tags: javascript

I was trying to make my code smaller by caching functions to variables.  For example:

```
function test(){
   var a = Array.prototype.slice,
   b = a.call(arguments);
   // Do something
   setTimeout(function(){
     var c = a.call(arguments);
     // Do something else
   }, 200);
}
```

So instead of calling `Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)`, I can just do `a.call(arguments);`.

I was trying to make this even smaller by caching `Array.prototype.slice.call`, but that wasn't working.

```
function test(){
   var a = Array.prototype.slice.call,
   b = a(arguments);
   // Do something
   setTimeout(function(){
     var c = a(arguments);
     // Do something else
   }, 200);
}
```

This gives me `TypeError: object is not a function`.  Why is that?

`typeof Array.prototype.slice.call` returns `"function"`, like expected.

Why can't I save `.call` to a variable (and then call it)?

Comment: which javascript engine gave you this error?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you reference Array.prototype.slice.call()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6835315/how-do-you-reference-array-prototype-slice-call)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Function.prototype.call` is an ordinary function that operates on the function passed as `this`.

When you call `call` from a variable, `this` becomes `window`, which is not a function.
You need to write `call.call(slice, someArray, arg1, arg2)`

Comment: Neat, that works.  `var a = Array.prototype.slice, b = a.call; b.call(a, arguments)`.  So, is there a way to "bind" `this` when copying `.call`?

Comment: @Rocket: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: So, `var a = Array.prototype.slice.call.bind(Array.prototype.slice)`?  Edit: Wow, that actually works!  Edit 2: According to the page `var slice = Function.prototype.call.bind(Array.prototype.slice);` works too!  Neat!

Comment: @Rocket: Or just `Function.call`.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
function test(){
   var a = function(args){
       return Array.prototype.slice.call(args);
   };
   b = a(arguments);
   // Do something
   setTimeout(function(){
     var c = a(arguments);
     // Do something else
   }, 200);
}
```

The same error will happen if you try doing something like:

```
var log = console.log;
log("Hello");
```

The reason is that when you do this you are assigning the function `x` (in my example `log`) to the variable `log`. **BUT** the function contains a call to `this` which now refers to `window` and not to `console`, which then throws an error that `this is not an object`

Comment: Weird, `var log = console.log; log('a');` gives `TypeError: Illegal invocation` in Chrome 16, but `var logX = console.log.bind(console); logX('a');` works :-P

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `call` is a method (a function that belongs to an object) that expects its owner (its `this`) to be a function. When you write `a = Array.prototype.slice.call`, you're copying the function, but not the owner.

The "object is not a function" message isn't saying that `a` isn't a function, it's saying that its `this` isn't a function. You could technically achieve what you describe by writing `a.call(Array.prototype.slice, arguments)`, but obviously that's not what you want!

Comment: Cool, `a.call(Array.prototype.slice, arguments)` actually works.  I figured that when you copied a function, `this` would be referenced correctly.

Comment: @Rocket: No -- it can't be -- because we need to be able to do something like `a.foo = b.foo` or `A.prototype.foo = B.prototype.foo` or whatnot to copy a method from one object to another. It would be terribly confusing if a call to `a.foo()` operated on `b` rather than `a`!